# Pandas variable type for comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a value in particular within a DataFrame in Pandas. To do so :

```
Result = df.loc[df["ROW_PRICE"] == ReferencePrice]
```

The problem is that if the variable type into the dataframe is different of the variable type of "ReferencePrice" the result will be empty.

Does anyone knows how can I transform the values of the dataframe into strings to compare them ? (I'll transform "ReferencePrice" into a string also -> str(ReferencePrice))

Comment: You mean `Result = df.loc[df["ROW_PRICE"].astype(str) == ReferencePrice]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need cast both to `string` for same type:

```
Result = df.loc[df["ROW_PRICE"].astype(str) == str(ReferencePrice)]
```